# Windows equivalent to "/dev/stdin"?

Tags: windows, stdin

I have Python code talking to a C++ library which only takes filenames. I want it to read from stdin. On Unix machines I can use "/dev/stdin". I thought I could use the special "CON" device on Windows, but that's more like /dev/tty in that "echo something | my_program" does not work.

Supporting pipes under Windows isn't essential, but now I'm curious. Is there something like the filename "/dev/stdin" for that OS?

Comment: It is CONIN$ on Windows.

Comment: @HansPassant Not exactly. `echo test | type CON` or `echo test | type CONIN$` *will read from the console, not from stdin*. Wheras the equivalent `echo test | cat /dev/stdin` on *nix will work, albeit it's a weird and backwards way to phrase the command.

Comment: Related: [Can you open stdin as a file on MS Windows in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959601/can-you-open-stdin-as-a-file-on-ms-windows-in-python)

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/q/241272/35237

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no equivalent of /dev/stdin.  However, if you really needed to you could create your own named pipe (CreateNamedPipe) and pass the name to the C++ library, using a separate thread to feed the input from stdin into the named pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent pseudo files on Windows are `conIN$` and `conOUT$`.

Comment: Those are not equivalent. The question says why (they act more like `/dev/tty`) and Criag Ringer's comment expands on it with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting your question - you know about cin and stdin, right?  If you need a real live winapi handle for ReadFile or whatever, use GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)

Comment: The "open file" function in the underlying C++ code takes a filename or a stream, but its Python bindings don't support the stream interface. I can only pass it a string filename and not cin or a file handle. Instead, I want to fake it out with something like "/dev/stdin".