# Can you open stdin as a file on MS Windows in Python?

Tags: python, windows, linux, stdin

On Linux, I'm using supbprocess.Popen to run an app. The command line of that app requires a path to an input file. I learned I can pass the path /dev/stdin to the command line, and then use Python's subproc.stdin.write() to send input to the subprocess.

```
import subprocess
kw['shell'] = False
kw['executable'] = '/path/to/myapp'
kw['stdin'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
subproc = subprocess.Popen(['','-i','/dev/stdin'],**kw)
inbuff = [u'my lines',u'of text',u'to process',u'go here']
outbuff = []
conditionbuff = []

def processdata(inbuff,outbuff,conditionbuff):
    for i,line in enumerate(inbuff):
        subproc.stdin.write('%s\n'%(line.encode('utf-8').strip()))
        line = subproc.stdout.readline().strip().decode('utf-8')
        if 'condition' in line:
            conditionbuff.append(line)
        else:
            outbuff.append(line)

processdata(inbuff,outbuff,conditionbuff)
```

There's also an MS Windows version of this app. Is there an equivalent on MS Windows to using the /dev/stdin or is the a Linux (Posix) specific solution?

Comment: Related: [Windows equivalent to "/dev/stdin"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395157/windows-equivalent-to-dev-stdin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myapp` treats `-` as a special filename that denotes stdin then:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen(['/path/to/myapp', '-i', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
stdout, _ = p.communicate('\n'.join(inbuff).encode('utf-8'))
outbuff = stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

If you can't pass `-` then you could use a temporary file:

```
import os
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(inbuff).encode('utf-8'))

p = Popen(['/path/to/myapp', '-i', f.name], stdout=PIPE)
outbuff, conditionbuff = [], []
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    line = line.strip().decode('utf-8')
    if 'condition' in line:
        conditionbuff.append(line)
    else:
        outbuff.append(line)
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
os.remove(f.name) #XXX add try/finally for proper cleanup
```

To suppress `stderr` you could pass `open(os.devnull, 'wb')` as `stderr` to `Popen`.

Comment: I tried '-' and this app doesn't support it. Also, in this case, communicate() wont work because I need line-by-line control not shown in this code.

Comment: @tahoar: could you update your question and elaborate what "line-by-line control" means in your case?

Comment: @sebastion: see updates. another issue with communicate() is that it might take some time (10-15 minutes) to load the process. This approach not only lets me work with the data line-by-line, but I can also call the loop multiple times without re-loading the app. I suspect that the STDIN issue is OS-specific and I'm limited to Posix platforms without changing the app I'm calling.

Comment: @tahoar: I've updated the answer to use temporary file as an input and read output line-by-line.

Comment: Yes, a temp file, of course. I wasn't thinking clearly. I can test for OS and use temp file on Window. Thanks.

Comment: @tahoar: The above code should work both on Linux and Windows. It is a maintenance burden to use different code on different OSes. Python allows you to use the same code; you could take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

Total shot in the dark, but `con:` is the name of the console device (you know, good ol' `copy con newfile.txt` from DOS). You might be able to pass `con:` as an argument to the program that won't accept '-'.