# How to generate a CSR without having a key file?

Tags: windows, node.js, openssl, certificate, csr

I am trying to run OpenSSL from Node.js in order to create a CSR. Basically, this works fine, but now I have a problem I can not solve.

Basically, what I want to do is to create a CSR from a key. The appropriate command is

```
$ openssl req -key private.key -new -subj "/C=DE/ST=..."
```

This outputs the CSR to stdout. So far, this is fine. What I now want to change is that I do not need to have the private key in a special file, instead I want to provide it from stdin. So, basically I'd like to run OpenSSL like this:

```
$ openssl req -new -subj "/C=DE/ST=..."
```

But since the `-key` parameter is now missing, this forces OpenSSL to create a new private key. How can I tell OpenSSL not to create a new private key, but to use the one I provide via stdin?

PS: I am aware of the option to hand over `/dev/stdin` to the `-key` parameter, but this will only work on OS X and Linux, not on Windows.

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395157/windows-equivalent-to-dev-stdin

Comment: Hm, more or less. The disadvantages are listed there as well. But, as it seems, there is no equal counterpart to /dev/stdin on Windows :-/

Comment: The private key should be securely stored.  Now it's *possible* to do that and still have it coming into openssl through stdin, but it's likely that if you're treating your private key carefully in the first place, you already have it in a file on the server where you're going to create the CSR, and you don't need to pipe it in from somewhere else.  This doesn't answer your question; it answers "Why does openssl assume your private key is in a file?"  Answer: Because it really should be, if you're doing things right.